# Getting null on controller side when calling ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to receive the string on the controller side. Please help me solve the issue. I will provide code snippets to expand on the problem.

Javascript code snippet:-

```
var GetMyQueueSearch = utilsBusiness.GetData(GetMyQueueSearchUrl + "?iUserId=" + iUserId);
var resultObj = JSON.stringify(GetMyQueueSearch.Data);
gridData = resultObj;         //global Variable
```

utilsBusiness.GetData is calling an ajax request using the url inside and return data of type:-

```
public object Data { get; set; }
public MessageCode MCode { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }
public bool Success { get; set; }
```

Ajax request snippet:-

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    jsonData = gridData;
    //jsonData2 = JSON.stringify(gridData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/ExportToExcel/',
        dataType: 'text',
        traditional: true,
        data: jsonData,
            beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

MVC side Controller code snippet:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string jsonData)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt;
    }
}
```

Here jsonData is coming as null. Please help me resolve this issue.

*If possible provide solution to send string only instead of changing the controller side input into a class.*

**Edit**:- Updated the code snippet with jsonData value.

Both jsonData and jsonData2 shows the same null value in the controller side.

**500 (Internal Server Error) is coming too.**

Comment: You have to show us jsonData if you want some help

Answer (score 1):

Usually we pass form data to controller by 2 ways:

1. Pass form data by binding fields name with the argument name in action method.
2. Bind form data with the model.

In your case you are trying to send the data without binding the field name with your data.

Try something like this:

Ajax request snippet:-

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/ExportToExcel/',
        dataType: 'text',
        traditional: true,
        data: { data: jsonData }, /* Replaced data: jsonData,*/
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It is still receiving null only. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

assuming jsonData is a string, you need to fix your API. There are two ways - to create text plain formatter or I recommed to use an http request body

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExportToExcel()
{
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {  
       string jsonData= await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

also replace " dataType: 'text' " with a content type

```
  contentType: 'text/plain',
```